# Showing two fragments for an ActionBar Tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, fragment

I used the Eclipse project wizard to create a project with an ActionBar and tabs. The wizard creates a dummy fragment for each tab with dummy text just showing the tab number. The app works without problems.

The code looks like this:

```
   @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the container

        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, tab.getPosition() + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

   /** 
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return textView;
        }
    }
```

For the purpose of my App I would like to show one fragment when the device is in portrait mode and two fragments when the device is in landscape mode. I know about the Shakespeare sample but in this sample it is an activity the holds the one or two fragments.

The Shakespeare sample uses two different layouts. For portrait mode (in "layout\fragment_layout_support.xml"):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class=".FragmentLayoutSupport$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and for landscape mode (in "layout-land\fragment_layout_support.xml"):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class=".FragmentLayoutSupport$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Shakespeare sample loads the layout like this:

```
public class FragmentLayoutSupport extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout_support);
    }
...
```

How do I do the same for my App where I cannot load the layout in a FragmentActivity?

Thanks.

Comment: I meant to say two listview fragments in the bounty.  Thanks for asking this @Ole

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're stuck because you don't know that [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) inherits [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) ?

So simply replace

```
extends FragmentActivity
```

with

```
extends ActionBarActivity
```

and the correct imports (see [ActionBar API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)). You will then be able to implement the same behaviour as in the Shakespeare sample while keeping your ActionBar/Tabs. Just extend the FragmentLayoutSupport instead of ActionBarActivity in your previously working activity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Another developer in our team solved it last year - and there's so much changed in the code since then so I'm unfortunately not able to say how it was solved. The suggested answer seems like a very good suggestion to what could have been wrong. So I'll give the answer a thumbs up.

Comment: Did not even look at the date ! I was just stuck myself for an hour not knowing that then I answered this question I found during the solving process.